# How do I pass parameters to an IOC constructor in MvvmCross?

Tags: inversion-of-control, mvvmcross

In the PCL Plugin, I have an interface, call it IFile. In my various platforms, PlatformFile. I can register using Mvx.RegisterType so that Mvx.Resolve will give me an IFile which is a PlatformFile. One of the PlatformFile constructors has a parameter, lets say the name so that

public PlatformFile(string name)

How do I Mvx.Resolve and pass in the name?

Answer (score 3):

You simply can't do this the way you are trying.

IoC/Service Location is built on top of C# interfaces.

Interfaces provide `contracts` in terms of Properties and Methods - but they do **not** include constructors.

---

The normal approach to this type of scenario is to provide an interface for a `IFileFactory` - this factory can then provide a `Create` method returning an `IFile`- e.g.

```
  public interface IFileFactory
  {
      IFile Create(string name);
  }
```

This is the approach taken in (for example) the MvvmCross SQLite plugin - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite/blob/master/Sqlite/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite/BaseClasses.cs - which registers an `ISQLiteConnectionFactory` object with the IoC container

```
public interface ISQLiteConnectionFactory
{
    ISQLiteConnection Create(string address);
}
```

---

For more on IoC see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control

Answer (score 1):

You can call constructor of PlatformFile when you create a new instance of that class, then register it as a singleton by calling Mvx.RegisterSingleton. Calling Mvx.Resolve, will allow you to resolve that instance of a class.